# Race condition with React Query

Tags: reactjs, race-condition, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm trying to create a Todo app with react query and I'm facing race condition issues.
I have a Todo page, the user update/create new todo, and clicks save.
the save process can take something like 3 seconds depends on the user internet connection.
After editing the Todo, the user remain in the todo page.
After creating new Todo, the user will be navigated to the todo page.

the issue is,
when a user create/update a todo and than click on show todo modal (which is external component, I can't edit it)
the modal is showing the todo before editing/empty if it's new todo

when I debugged the issue, I can see that react query fetching the todo after the modal is opened.
If I close the modal and open it again it will show the updated todo.

```
const {todo} = useTodoQuery()

const openModal = () => modal.open(todo)

return (
   <TodoModalButton onClick={openModal}>Open Todo Preview Modal</TodoModalButton>
)
```

```
const useTodoQuery = () => {
  const {data, ...rest} = useQuery(['todo', todoId], async () => {
    if (todoId) {
      return await getTodo(todoId)
    }
    return null;
  })

  return {data, ...rest}
}
```

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    suspense: false,
    keepPreviousData: true,
  }
})
```

if i remove the keepPreviousData the todo will be undefined.

```
  const todoMutation = useMutation(
    ['todo'],
    getUpdatedTodo,
    {onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(['todo', todoId])}
  );
```

I've tried using
`{onSuccess: (todo) => queryClient.setQueryData(['todo', todoId], todo)}`
but it didn't worked as well.

Comment: this is not a race condition problem, this is how the async word works. You better try putting some busy indicator and hold until data is ready.

Comment: there isn't another way? I want to wait for the onSuccess somehow and than open the modal

Answer (score 0):

just wait onSuccess callback and after open model :) solve :D

if it's not possible give more details

Comment: how can you wait for the on success in react-query?